# Are the three statements the same?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

Let $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the Schwartz function on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider two statements which have the same proof.
$$ f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)\,\,\Longrightarrow\,\,f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$$
and
$$\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset L^p(\mathbb{R}^n).$$

My question is, if we know the fact $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a subspace of $L^p$, does this imply $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)?$

In other words, the three statements are equivalent.
\begin{align*}
f\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)\,\,&\Longrightarrow\,\,f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n),\\
\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)&\subset L^p(\mathbb{R}^n),\\
\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)\quad&\text{is dense}\quad\text{in}\quad L^p(\mathbb{R}^n).
\end{align*}

Could anyone correct my mistakes? How to prove $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)?$

Comment: The first two are equivalent but not the last one.  From $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n) \Rightarrow f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ you cannot infer that $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$. A proof is needed.

Comment: page 5 http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~stein/lehre/SoSem08/sobolev_fourier.pdf seems telling me they 3 the same. If not, how can I deduce the last one?

Comment: That is because $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n) \subseteq \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and you have probably seen that $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n) $ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: No, this is not the important part of the argument. $\subseteq$ and $\subset$ mean the same here.

Comment: Lemma1.5 is proving $\mathcal{D}$ is dense in $L^p$. But I want the proof of $\mathcal{S}$ is dense in $L^p$

Comment: $\mathcal{D}$ is the set of test functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. smooth functions of compact support. whereas $\mathbb{S}$ is the set of Schwartz function, i.e. smooth functions of rapid decay. More precise definitions are provided in your notes. The important part here is that test functions are also  Schwartz functions (but the converse is not true). Moreover tests functions are dense in $L^p$. Therefore Schwartz functions are dense in $L^p$ (how could it be otherwise since even a subset of Schwartz function - namely the set of test functions - is dense in $L^p$ ?!)

Comment: I do not understand your last sentence (in the bracket), but I know that $C_0^{\infty}\subset \mathcal{S}\subset L^p$, hence both $C_0^{\infty}$ and $\mathcal{S}$ are dense in $L^p$.

Comment: You know that $C_0^\infty \subset \mathbb{S} \subset L^p$ and you know from Lemma 1.5 that $C_0^\infty$ is dense in $L^p$. From these two facts (you need both facts) you can conclude that $\mathcal{S}$ is dense in $L^p$.

Comment: I'm under the impression that you are inclined to think that density can somehow be derived from set-inclusion statements like : $C_0^\infty \subset \mathcal{S} \subset L^p$. It cannot. Density is a topological statement and requires a topological argument, such as the one provided in Lemma 1.5. It is once you've got Lemma 1.5 and only then that you can use the set-inclusion relation to extract some more information such as "$\mathcal{S}$ is dense in $L^p$".

Comment: @M.G As you said that density is a topological argument...my background on topology is rather weak. I was trying to find things like how to prove X is dense in Y in my analysis book but couldn't find anything like wt ou said. Could you suggest some text on topology that may help?

Comment: @M.G For instance, in your additional comment you use the idea of neighborhood to explain the density argument, I would like to know a standard ref. That may help me gain a better feeling...

Comment: I suggest James Munkres' Topology http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/munkres2.pdf. The definition of dense subsets is in Chapter 4 but what you really need in order to understand density is the notion of closure and that of limit points. You will find these in Chapter 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

> $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$

cannot be infered from

> $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n) \Rightarrow f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

What is said in the notes that you're refering to is :

> $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ because
>   $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n) \subseteq \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and it has been established in Lemma 1.5 that
>   $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n) $ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

**Additional comment :**  What does "$X$ is dense in $Y$ mean ? It means that every neighbourhood of every $y \in Y$ contain an element of $x$, i.e. fix a $y \in Y$ at random and select any neighbourhood of this $y \in Y$ then there ought to be a $x \in X$ in this neighbourhood.

Whenever you can prove that $X$ is dense in $Y$ and that $X \subseteq Z \subseteq Y$ than you can conclude that $Z$ is dense in $Y$ too.

Why ? Well fix $y \in Y$ and fix a neighbourhood of $y$. This neighbourhood contains a certain $x \in X$ because $X$ is dense in $Y$ by hypothesis. But $x \in X \subseteq Z$. Therefore you can see $x$ as an element of $Z$ and conclude that every neighbourhood of any $y \in Y$ contain an element of $Z$.

**Example :**  I'll answer the question you asked in a comment here. Define $$X := \big\{ (q_1, q_2) :~~ q_1, q_2 \in \mathbb{Q}\big\}\\ Z := \big\{ (q, r) :~~ q \in \mathbb{Q}, r \in \mathbb{R}\big\} \\ Y := \big\{ (r_1, r_2) :~~ r_1, r_2 \in \mathbb{R}\big\}= \mathbb{R}^2.$$

Clearly $X \subseteq Z \subseteq Y$. Also you can easily prove that $X$ is dense in $Y$.

Now, can we readily conclude that $Z$ is dense in $Y$ (that is without having to provide a proof) ? Yes ! And here is why :

Let $(r_1, r_2)$ be any element of $Y= \mathbb{R}^2$ and consider a neighbourhood of $(r_1, r_2)$. This neighbourhood contains an element $(q_1, q_2)$ of $X$ (because we know that $X$ is dense in $Y$). Hence this neighbourhood contains an element of $Z$, namely $(q_1, q_2)$ itself. This concludes the proof that $Z$ is dense in $Y$.

Comment: what does it mean by "every neighbourhood of every $y\in Y$...I think there is a mistake in this sentence...the second 'every' is redundant?

Comment: I do not get your answer, we do not know the relationship between $Y$ and $Z$, whether $Z\subset Y$, or...how could you conclude $Z$ is dense in $Y$?

Comment: I provided some more details.